# How to increase the date range to 3 days from now using JMeter HTTP request?

Tags: jmeter

In the example below, I would like to set the end date to a date which is 3 or 5 days from the start date, for now my request is sending:

```
startDate=2019-01-03T09:38:00.452Z&endDate=2019-01-03T09:38:00.452Z
```

But I need to be sent as:

```
startDate=2019-01-03T09:38:00.452Z&endDate=2019-01-06T09:38:00.452Z
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [__timeShift() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) which can generate times and dates in different formats with different offsets so function call like:

```
${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss:SS'Z',,P3D,,)}
```

should be something you're looking for:

[image]

Check out [Creating Dates in JMeter Using the TimeShift Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function) article for more information if needed.